# Add bitmap to resource

Tags: arrays, vb.net, bitmap, resources

I am trying to add compressed bitmap as resource of another executable, but got stuck to an error. The error is:

```
Value of type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of System.Drawing.Bitmap'
```

Here's my pseudo code:

Module1:

```
    Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Module ResourceWriter
    Private Function ToPtr(ByVal data As Object) As IntPtr
        Dim h As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned)
        Dim ptr As IntPtr
        Try
            ptr = h.AddrOfPinnedObject()
        Finally
            h.Free()
        End Try
        Return ptr

    End Function

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Function UpdateResource(ByVal hUpdate As IntPtr, ByVal lpType As String, ByVal lpName As String, ByVal wLanguage As UShort, ByVal lpData As IntPtr, ByVal cbData As UInteger) As Boolean
    End Function
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Function BeginUpdateResource(ByVal pFileName As String, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> ByVal bDeleteExistingResources As Boolean) As IntPtr
    End Function
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Function EndUpdateResource(ByVal hUpdate As IntPtr, ByVal fDiscard As Boolean) As Boolean
    End Function

    Public Function WriteResource(ByVal filename As String, ByVal bmp As Bitmap()) As Boolean

        Try
            Dim handle As IntPtr = BeginUpdateResource(filename, False)
            Dim file1 As Bitmap() = bmp
            Dim fileptr As IntPtr = ToPtr(file1)
            Dim res As Boolean = UpdateResource(handle, "BitMaps", "0", 0, fileptr, Convert.ToUInt32(file1.Length))
            EndUpdateResource(handle, False)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
        Return True

    End Function
End Module
```

In form, under button:

```
'...here's code to compress the image, commented out for now
Dim bmp1 As Bitmap = Compressed
WriteResource("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Testfile.exe", bmp1)
```

But it doesn't work. What changes I should make to the module, or to the code under button? I see I should convert *System.Drawing.Bitmap* to *1-dimensional array* before putting the image into the resources, but how?

Any help is much appreciated :)

**Edit:**

I have now tried all answers I found from google & MSDN, and I cannot figure it out. So if anyone could just show how to do it, I would really appreciate it..
Here's one of the methods I tried.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        '...
        Dim bmp1 As Bitmap = Compressed
        Dim Converted = ConvertToByteArray(bmp1)
        WriteResource("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Testfile.exe", Converted)
    End Sub
    Public Shared Function ConvertToByteArray(ByVal value As Bitmap) As Byte()
        Dim bitmapBytes As Byte()
        Using stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
            value.Save(stream, value.RawFormat)
            bitmapBytes = stream.ToArray
        End Using
        Return bitmapBytes
    End Function
```

And yes, I changed the Bitmap() to Byte() at Module1; but it returned `"Value cannot be NULL"` in runtime.

I also tried to save it as `IO.MemoryStream` and then convert to bytes but didn't success.

So if *anyone* could show me how to do this, that would be really great.

Comment: if you are trying to write one single bitmap, why are you passing an array of them to WriteResource?

Comment: what exactly is the error? hold the mouse over bitmapbytes - how big is it (or check the return)...did you change the params for  `UpdateResource` in WriteResource?  I think I know what is wrong, but `Didn't success` is pretty vague for debugging via comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem you have is well covered in Ryan's answer (`Dim file1 As Bitmap() = bmp` is wrong too); the second is that you are covering up a different problem.

If you refer to [UpdateResource on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you'll see that `cbdata` is the number of bytes to write, that is the byte count of the bitmap.  Your code is passing the size of the array.    Further, `lpData` is supposed to be a long pointer to the data and also "`Note that this is the raw binary data to be stored`".  You cannot just pass a bitmap as you are trying to do.

The bitmap class's save method will let you save to a memorystream from which the bytes AND BYTE COUNT can be gotten and fed to UpdateResource.

Comment: Okay well.. I can save the bmp1 with bmp1.Save("...") so the error is adding the resource. Would it be easier to save the file to disk before adding it into the resources? Can somebody show some simple example related to my code? None of the answers haven't helped yet.

Comment: STUDY the page at MSDN to know what you need to do.  If saving to disk was the best first step, we would not BOTH have mentioned saving it to a Memorystream.  Put together code to get your bitmap -> memstream -> byte() and post code for whatever you get stuck on.

Comment: Updated the post. Didn't success with converting it to bytearray nor saving it to memstream + then to bytes...

Comment: Still looking help for this, haven't succeed with it yet :\

Answer (score 1):

You declared the parameter as a Bitmap array by putting () after the type name here:

```
Public Function WriteResource(ByVal filename As String, ByVal bmp As Bitmap()) As Boolean
```

If you don't want it to be an array, remove the ():

```
Public Function WriteResource(ByVal filename As String, ByVal bmp As Bitmap) As Boolean
```

Comment: I already tried this, and many other combinations, but then I will have an error in the module. This:   _Dim res As Boolean = UpdateResource(handle, "BitMaps", "0", 0, fileptr, Convert.ToUInt32(file1.Length))_ <----- file1.Length is not a member of system.drawing.bitmap

Comment: @user2404495  but the length of file1 is the size of the array not the number of bytes to write, so dispensing of that error actually made things worse...or at least did not solve anything.

Comment: The code you have here is a very long way away from working. For example, writing the managed bitmap data from memory instead of an actual Bitmap file is not going to result in a working resource. You should try calling .Save on the Bitmap into a MemoryStream and using the bytes from the MemoryStream instead (with GetBuffer).